# Can macd be calculated for values other than 12 and 26?

Tags: python, time-series, finance, ta-lib

I am working on time-series classification problem using CNN. The dataset used is financial stock market data (like Yahoo Finance). I am using some technical indicators calculated using raw values high,low,volume,open,close.

One of the technical indicators is MACD (Moving Average Convergence Divergence) using [TA Library](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/technical-analysis-library-in-python/latest/technical-analysis-library-in-python.pdf). However, it is written, in most places, that it is calculated for n_fast = 12 and n_slow = 26 periods with RSI (Relative Strength Index) being calculated for 14 days and n_sign = 9 (parameter of macd_diff() in ta library).

So, if I am calculating RSI for 5 days period then how do we set these n_fast and n_slow values according to it? Should these be n_fast = 3 and n_slow = 8. Also, what should be the value of n_sign then? I am new to finance domain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is domain-specific and not a programming problem; Stack Overflow is for issues with code in particular, not about parameters of some model. Instead, I would suggest checking out https://quant.stackexchange.com/ or https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about financial algorithms and not programming.

Comment: Also voted to close as off-topic.